# bogus warning on write to pointer

Tags: c, frama-c

I am a very newbie with Frama-c and have a very short program which causes frama-c to claim that 'out of bounds write.  assert\valid(iptr):

f4.c:33:[kernel] **warning: out of bounds write. assert \valid(iptr);**
f4.c:34:[value] Assigning imprecise value to __retres.

I don't see it.  Help?
I don't understand what the next line means either...

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*
 * f4.c example of a 'valid' clause:
 * foo 
 * and abort.
 *
 * cmd line: frama-c -val f4.c
 */

int fill( int * iptr, int length );

const int BUF_SIZE = 100;
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int * ptr = malloc( BUF_SIZE * sizeof( int ));
    memset( ptr, 0x00,  BUF_SIZE * sizeof( int ));
    int rv = fill( ptr, BUF_SIZE );
    printf("rv = %d\n", rv); 
    return 0;
}


/* 
 * @requires  \valid(iptr+(0..length+1));
 * @requires length >= 1;
 * @assigns *iptr;
 */

int fill( int * iptr,  int length )
{
    *iptr = 3;
    return( *iptr );
}
```

output:
...framac [0] > frama-c -val -wp f4.c

```
[kernel] preprocessing with "gcc -C -E -I.  f4.c"
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:47:[kernel] warning: Calling undeclared function __builtin_bswap32. Old style K&R code?
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/byteswap.h:111:[kernel] warning: Calling undeclared function __builtin_bswap64. Old style K&R code?
[value] Analyzing a complete application starting at main
[value] Computing initial state
[value] Initial state computed
[value] Values of globals at initialization
        BUF_SIZE ∈ {100}
[value] computing for function malloc <- main.
        Called from f4.c:17.
[kernel] warning: Neither code nor specification for function malloc, generating default assigns from the prototype
[value] using specification for function malloc
[value] Done for function malloc
[value] computing for function memset <- main.
        Called from f4.c:18.
[kernel] warning: Neither code nor specification for function memset, generating default assigns from the prototype
[value] using specification for function memset
[value] Done for function memset
[value] computing for function fill <- main.
        Called from f4.c:19.
**f4.c:33:[kernel] **warning: out of bounds write. assert \valid(iptr);**
f4.c:34:[value] Assigning imprecise value to __retres.**
        The imprecision originates from Library function {f4.c:17}
[value] Recording results for fill
[value] Done for function fill
f4.c:20:[value] Reading left-value rv.
        It contains a garbled mix of {alloced_return_malloc} because of
        Library function {f4.c:17}.
[value] computing for function printf <- main.
        Called from f4.c:20.
[kernel] warning: Neither code nor specification for function printf, generating default assigns from the prototype
[value] using specification for function printf
[value] Done for function printf
[value] Recording results for main
[value] done for function main
[value] ====== VALUES COMPUTED ======
[value] Values at end of function fill:
          __retres ∈
                  {{ garbled mix of &{alloced_return_malloc}
                   (origin: Library function {f4.c:17}) }}
          alloced_return_malloc[...] ∈
                               {{ garbled mix of &{alloced_return_malloc}
                                (origin: Library function {f4.c:17}) }}
[value] Values at end of function main:
          ptr ∈ {{ NULL + [--..--] ; &alloced_return_malloc + [0..2147483647] }}
          rv ∈
            {{ garbled mix of &{alloced_return_malloc}
             (origin: Library function {f4.c:17}) }}
          __retres ∈ {0}
          alloced_return_malloc[...] ∈
                               {{ garbled mix of &{alloced_return_malloc}
                                (origin: Library function {f4.c:17}) }}
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that my 'requires' statement is incorrect in this version.  Changing it to length-1 has no effect on the problem.  I was trying to get that to fail (which is another problem).

Comment: Note: `return` is a statement, not a function. Using parentesis for the expression is deprecated.

Comment: @Olaf Eh... How so? I have no idea what you think is deprecated.

Comment: @FUZxxl: The parentheses are not part of the statement,but of the expression. Thus they make a nested expression like `(i);` for an expression statement. Both are useless and do not add to readability. Just in case you confused that: I did not write it was deprecated by the standard.

Comment: old habit... I like them (), but I know I'm in the minority.  I also hate expressions in return statements, but I don't wanna start a flame war... :)

Comment: @NotCharlie: I don't want to either. Just to clarify: I'm the first to add parentesis to enhance readbility, e.g. `(i <1) || (i >10)`. But here it does not. Btw. how do you `return` aq value without an _expression_?? It is not possible.

Comment: I know very little about frama-c, but is it expected to understand the effects of `malloc()` in securing memory?  Is it expected to somehow overlook the possibility that `malloc()` fails, maybe because of the the `memset()` call between `malloc()` and `fill()`?

Comment: Or is it perhaps the case that the static validation you are trying to perform only works when the actual argument is declared as an array?

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions (`malloc()` in this case) always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when compiling, enable all the warnings.  then fix those warnings.  1) unused parameter 'argc' 2) unused parameter: 'argv' 3) unused parameter 'length'  For 1 and 2 change the signature of the main() function to `int main( void )`

Comment: this is C, so instead of: `const int BUF_SIZE = 100;` use: `#define BUF_SIZE (100)`.  (also if implicit conversions are being flagged, then the parameter passed to `malloc()` will not raise any warnings

Comment: regarding the doxygen statements for the `length` parameter of the `fill()` function:  the contents of `length` must be >= sizeof int.

Comment: it is sloppy programming to let the OS cleanup after the executed code.  I.E. before returning from `main()`  insert the statement: `free( ptr );`

Comment: @Olaf Methinks someone is being a bit too pedantic :)  What I meant was return( x ) vs. return( call_function_to_compute_x());  Makes it harder to debug, harder to read -- no benefit.

Comment: @user3629249:  you are correct, but that was not intended to be production code -- smallest example of problem which is with the *frama-c* tool.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotCharlie: Both are expressions. That has nothing to do with pedantry, but in C even `a = 1` is an expression. FYI: `int a = 1;` is not, `a = 1;` is a statement (guess what makes an expression a statement). Tell you compiler to be too pedantic if it does not understand `A` is the same as `a`. And with a halfway modern compiler your examples actually might generate the same code. and can complicate debugging either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bulk of your issue lies in the following warnings:

```
[value] computing for function malloc <- main.
        Called from f4.c:17.
[kernel] warning: Neither code nor specification for function malloc, generating default assigns from the prototype
[value] using specification for function malloc
```

Basically, the `malloc` function has no implementation and no ACSL specification, so that Value Analysis does not know what to do with it, and returns a very imprecise result (namely `{{ garbled mix of &{alloced_return_malloc} (origin: Library function {f4.c:17}) }}`). Starting from there, false alarms can be expected to flow.

If you intend to provide a suitable initial context for the `fill` function, you should use a static array instead. Public releases of Frama-C do not provide built-ins for `malloc`, and emulating them in pure C will probably not get you very far.

In addition, please note that the comment before the `fill` function is **not** an ACSL specification. Those are introduced by `/*@`, not by `/*` followed somewhere later by an `@`.